# xrandr: Cannot set resolution of laptop display

Tags: display, laptop, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a laptop which has a max. resolution of 2880x1800. I want to set the resolution to something like 1920x1200. I tried

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1200
```

but I get the error

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

I also tried to specify several refresh rates with always the same result. What could I try to change the resolution?

This is the output of xrandr --verbose:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6320 x 1800, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 2880x1800+0+0 (0x49) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 302mm x 188mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  3005899
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000e6f021400000000
        001e0104b51e137802ee95a3544c9926
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101b6c840a0b0084e703020
        36002ebc100000180000000000000000
        00000000000000000018000000fe0043
        534f542054330a2020202020000000fe
        004d4e453030375a41312d310a2000d3
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Fixed_Point, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Floating_Point, opRGB, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, BT2020_RGB, BT601_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    panel orientation: Normal 
        supported: Normal, Upside Down, Left Side Up, Right Side Up
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 236 
        supported: 236
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  2880x1800 (0x49) 513.820MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  2880 start 2928 end 2960 total 3040 skew    0 clock 169.02KHz
        v: height 1800 start 1803 end 1809 total 1878           clock  90.00Hz
  2880x1620 (0x4a) 396.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2880 start 3096 end 3408 total 3936 skew    0 clock 100.67KHz
        v: height 1620 start 1623 end 1628 total 1679           clock  59.96Hz
  2880x1620 (0x4b) 303.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2880 start 2928 end 2960 total 3040 skew    0 clock  99.92KHz
        v: height 1620 start 1623 end 1628 total 1666           clock  59.97Hz
  2560x1600 (0x4c) 348.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2760 end 3032 total 3504 skew    0 clock  99.46KHz
        v: height 1600 start 1603 end 1609 total 1658           clock  59.99Hz
  2560x1600 (0x4d) 268.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock  98.71KHz
        v: height 1600 start 1603 end 1609 total 1646           clock  59.97Hz
  2560x1440 (0x4e) 638.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  2560 start 2780 end 3064 total 3568 skew    0 clock 178.88KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1441 end 1444 total 1491           clock  59.99Hz
  2560x1440 (0x4f) 469.125MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  2560 start 2584 end 2600 total 2640 skew    0 clock 177.70KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1441 end 1444 total 1481           clock  59.99Hz
  2560x1440 (0x50) 312.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.96Hz
  2560x1440 (0x51) 241.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1481           clock  59.95Hz
  2048x1536 (0x52) 388.040MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2216 end 2440 total 2832 skew    0 clock 137.02KHz
        v: height 1536 start 1537 end 1540 total 1612           clock  85.00Hz
  2048x1536 (0x53) 340.480MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2216 end 2440 total 2832 skew    0 clock 120.23KHz
        v: height 1536 start 1537 end 1540 total 1603           clock  75.00Hz
  2048x1536 (0x54) 266.950MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2200 end 2424 total 2800 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height 1536 start 1537 end 1540 total 1589           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1440 (0x55) 341.350MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2072 end 2288 total 2656 skew    0 clock 128.52KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1441 end 1444 total 1512           clock  85.00Hz
  1920x1440 (0x56) 297.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2064 end 2288 total 2640 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1441 end 1444 total 1500           clock  75.00Hz
  1920x1440 (0x57) 234.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2256 total 2600 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1441 end 1444 total 1500           clock  60.00Hz
  1856x1392 (0x58) 288.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1856 start 1984 end 2208 total 2560 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height 1392 start 1393 end 1396 total 1500           clock  75.00Hz
  1856x1392 (0x59) 218.300MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1856 start 1952 end 2176 total 2528 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height 1392 start 1393 end 1396 total 1439           clock  60.01Hz
  1792x1344 (0x5a) 261.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1792 start 1888 end 2104 total 2456 skew    0 clock 106.27KHz
        v: height 1344 start 1345 end 1348 total 1417           clock  75.00Hz
  1792x1344 (0x5b) 204.800MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1792 start 1920 end 2120 total 2448 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height 1344 start 1345 end 1348 total 1394           clock  60.01Hz
  2048x1152 (0x5c) 406.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  2048 start 2220 end 2444 total 2840 skew    0 clock 143.13KHz
        v: height 1152 start 1153 end 1156 total 1193           clock  59.99Hz
  2048x1152 (0x5d) 302.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  2048 start 2072 end 2088 total 2128 skew    0 clock 142.15KHz
        v: height 1152 start 1153 end 1156 total 1185           clock  59.98Hz
  2048x1152 (0x5e) 197.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2184 end 2400 total 2752 skew    0 clock  71.58KHz
        v: height 1152 start 1155 end 1160 total 1195           clock  59.90Hz
  2048x1152 (0x5f) 156.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2096 end 2128 total 2208 skew    0 clock  70.99KHz
        v: height 1152 start 1155 end 1160 total 1185           clock  59.91Hz
  1920x1200 (0x60) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
  1920x1200 (0x61) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0x62) 356.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1920 start 2080 end 2288 total 2656 skew    0 clock 134.18KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock  60.01Hz
  1920x1080 (0x63) 266.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1920 start 1944 end 1960 total 2000 skew    0 clock 133.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1111           clock  59.97Hz
  1920x1080 (0x64) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
  1920x1080 (0x65) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1600x1200 (0x66) 229.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock 106.25KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  85.00Hz
  1600x1200 (0x67) 202.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  93.75KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  75.00Hz
  1600x1200 (0x68) 189.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  87.50KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  70.00Hz
  1600x1200 (0x69) 175.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  81.25KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  65.00Hz
  1600x1200 (0x6a) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x6b) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1680x1050 (0x6c) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1400x1050 (0x6d) 155.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1464 end 1784 total 1912 skew    0 clock  81.49KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1090           clock  74.76Hz
  1400x1050 (0x6e) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz
  1600x900 (0x6f) 246.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1728 end 1900 total 2200 skew    0 clock 111.82KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock  59.99Hz
  1600x900 (0x70) 186.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1640 total 1680 skew    0 clock 111.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  926           clock  59.94Hz
  1600x900 (0x71) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1600x900 (0x72) 97.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  59.82Hz
  1280x1024 (0x73) 157.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock  91.15KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1072           clock  85.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x74) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x75) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1400x900 (0x76) 103.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1480 end 1624 total 1848 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  934           clock  59.96Hz
  1400x900 (0x77) 86.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x960 (0x78) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock  85.94KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1011           clock  85.00Hz
  1280x960 (0x79) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x7a) 198.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1548 end 1704 total 1968 skew    0 clock 100.67KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  839           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x7b) 151.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1480 total 1520 skew    0 clock  99.92KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  833           clock  59.97Hz
  1368x768 (0x7c) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
  1368x768 (0x7d) 72.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.85Hz
  1280x800 (0x7e) 174.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1380 end 1516 total 1752 skew    0 clock  99.46KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  829           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x800 (0x7f) 134.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  98.71KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  823           clock  59.97Hz
  1280x800 (0x80) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1280x800 (0x81) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x82) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x83) 156.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1512 total 1744 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x84) 120.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  740           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x720 (0x85) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1280x720 (0x86) 63.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  59.74Hz
  1024x768 (0x87) 194.020MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1108 end 1220 total 1416 skew    0 clock 137.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  806           clock  85.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x88) 170.240MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1108 end 1220 total 1416 skew    0 clock 120.23KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  801           clock  75.05Hz
  1024x768 (0x89) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x8a) 94.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1168 total 1376 skew    0 clock  68.68KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  808           clock  85.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x8b) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x8c) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x8d) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768i (0x8e) 44.900MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1024 start 1032 end 1208 total 1264 skew    0 clock  35.52KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  776 total  817           clock  86.96Hz
  960x720 (0x8f) 170.675MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1036 end 1144 total 1328 skew    0 clock 128.52KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  756           clock  85.00Hz
  960x720 (0x90) 148.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1032 end 1144 total 1320 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  75.00Hz
  960x720 (0x91) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x92) 144.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  992 end 1104 total 1280 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  750           clock  75.00Hz
  928x696 (0x93) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x94) 130.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  944 end 1052 total 1228 skew    0 clock 106.27KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  708           clock  75.05Hz
  896x672 (0x95) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  1024x576 (0x96) 98.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1092 end 1200 total 1376 skew    0 clock  71.58KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  59.95Hz
  1024x576 (0x97) 78.375MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1064 total 1104 skew    0 clock  70.99KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  592           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x576 (0x98) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  1024x576 (0x99) 42.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  59.82Hz
  960x600 (0x9a) 96.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1028 end 1128 total 1296 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  622           clock  59.93Hz
  960x600 (0x9b) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x9c) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  960x540 (0x9d) 86.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1124 total 1288 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  560           clock  59.96Hz
  960x540 (0x9e) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  960x540 (0x9f) 40.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   960 start  992 end 1088 total 1216 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  562           clock  59.63Hz
  960x540 (0xa0) 37.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock  59.82Hz
  800x600 (0xa1) 114.750MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock 106.25KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  85.00Hz
  800x600 (0xa2) 101.250MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  93.75KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0xa3) 94.500MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  87.50KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  70.00Hz
  800x600 (0xa4) 87.750MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  81.25KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  65.00Hz
  800x600 (0xa5) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0xa6) 56.300MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  832 end  896 total 1048 skew    0 clock  53.72KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  631           clock  85.14Hz
  800x600 (0xa7) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0xa8) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0xa9) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0xaa) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  840x525 (0xab) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0xac) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  864x486 (0xad) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
  864x486 (0xae) 30.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock  59.57Hz
  700x525 (0xaf) 77.900MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  732 end  892 total  956 skew    0 clock  81.49KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  545           clock  74.76Hz
  700x525 (0xb0) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  800x450 (0xb1) 59.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  848 end  928 total 1056 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.95Hz
  800x450 (0xb2) 48.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock  59.82Hz
  640x512 (0xb3) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  672 end  752 total  864 skew    0 clock  91.15KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  536           clock  85.02Hz
  640x512 (0xb4) 67.500MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  648 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  75.02Hz
  640x512 (0xb5) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  700x450 (0xb6) 51.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  740 end  812 total  924 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  467           clock  59.96Hz
  700x450 (0xb7) 43.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock  59.88Hz
  640x480 (0xb8) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  672 end  752 total  864 skew    0 clock  85.94KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  505           clock  85.09Hz
  640x480 (0xb9) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0xba) 36.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  696 end  752 total  832 skew    0 clock  43.27KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  509           clock  85.01Hz
  640x480 (0xbb) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0xbc) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :-) I had kernel 6.0 installed. After downgrading to 5.15 I could set the display resolution. Thanks to the guys of Tuxedo Computers.